# how SQL injection is done?

Tags: security, sql-injection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XKCD SQL injection - please explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain)

What is the general concept behind sql injection ?

Being a rails developer

This is unsafe

```
  Booking.find(:all, :conditions => [ 'bookings.user_id = #{params[user_id]]}'] )
```

and this is safe:--

```
 Booking.find(:all, :conditions => [ 'bookings.user_id = ?', params[user_id]] )
```

am i right?

So my question is how the sql injection is done? 
How those guys do some stuff like that. Any live example/ tutorial where somebody is showing this kind of stuff. Anything basic for knowing the logic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XKCD SQL injection - please explain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain) and a [couple others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+injection)

Comment: Voting to close my own question for the first time :-(. but its good. My mistake to ask a question like this before searching on stackoverflow. Sorry guys. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Injection happens when a programmer gets lazy. A vulnerable query would look like this:

```
DECLARE @cmd varchar(256)

SET cmd='SELECT @col FROM Table'
EXEC @cmd
```

With @col being a variable passed into a stored procedure.

Usually, the user would enter a column in that already exists for that variable. But a more devious user could enter something like this:

```
* FROM Table; DROP DATABASE data;--
```

The * FROM Table; finishes off the previous statement. Then, DROP DATABASE data; is the payload that does bad things, in this case, dropping the database. Finally, the -- comments out the rest of the query so it doesn't get any errors from the injection.

So, instead of executing this:

```
SELECT column
FROM Table
```

You get this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table;
DROP DATABASE data;
--
```

Which is not good.

And this:
[image]

Comment: Voted up for XKCD. Writing out the example from the comic and what exactly happens would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

All the user has to do is enter:

```
1234; DROP TABLE BOOKINGS
```

...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about rails, but by doing this `Booking.find(:all, :conditions => [ 'bookings.user_id = #{params[user_id]]}'] )`, you risk that the user give to user_id the value `1 OR 1=1` and as you can see, it will modify your request.

With more injection you could do something like `1; DROP TABLE BOOKINGS` etc.

Basically injection is just "hijacking" a basic request to add yours.

[Bobby tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a simple query like

SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE user_id =  ORDER BY user_id ASC;

if you don't check user id, it can close your query, then start a new (harmful one) and discard the rest. To achieve this, generally, you would enter something like

1; DELETE FROM bookings; --

initial ; closes the good query, the bad query comes next, then it is closed with ; and -- makes sure that anything that would come next in the good query is commented out. You then end up with

SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE user_id = 1; DELETE FROM bookings; -- ORDER BY user_id ASC;

Answer (score 0):

If your data in properly cleaned and sanatized, a user can try to get their own SQL code to run on the server. for example, let's say you have a query like this:

```
 "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_type = $type"
```

where type is unchanged user input from a text field. now, if I were to search for this type:

(DELETE FROM products)

You are gonna be in a world of hurt. This is why it's important to make sure all user input in sanatized before running it in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of excellent papers on the theory of SQL injection here:

[sql injection filetype:pdf](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&rls=com.microsoft%3Aen-gb%3AIE-SearchBox&as_q=sql+injection&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&num=10&lr=&as_filetype=pdf&ft=i&as_sitesearch=&as_qdr=all&as_rights=&as_occt=any&cr=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&safe=off)

Should be easy enough to hunt one down that is specific to your language/DB combination.